# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://media/external/video/media }

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, video-capture, android-gallery

Its been 5 days of struggling for this issue and still didn't get any working solution.At last thought of getting help from the genius minds here.
**Issue:**
I am trying to pick a video from the gallery (But in some tablet devices version 28)getting the above exception. I would like to state that some are amazon tablets, so I am not sure if any specific checks required on this.
Below is my code:

```
     private fun selectVideo() {
            val items = arrayOf<CharSequence>("Camera", "Gallery", "Cancel")
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            builder.setTitle("Add Attachment")
            builder.setItems(items) { dialog, item ->
    
                if (items[item] == "Camera") {
                    val videoCaptureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
                    videoCaptureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 20);
    
                    if (videoCaptureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                        startActivityForResult(videoCaptureIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
                    }
                } else if (items[item] == "Gallery") {
                    
                        val galleryIntent = Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                        )
                        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_PICK)
    
                    }
                }
            }
            builder.show()
    
        }
```

Your kind support will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
var intent = new Intent ();
intent.SetType ("video/*");
intent.SetAction (Intent.ActionGetContent);
intent.PutExtra (MediaStore.ExtraVideoQuality, 0);
intent.PutExtra (MediaStore.ExtraDurationLimit, Globals.VideoMaxDuration);
this.StartActivityForResult (Intent.CreateChooser (intent, "Select video"), 200);
```